# Drupal:After installing boost module, images are not uploaded in files/imagecache

Tags: image, drupal, drupal-boost

Title explains it pretty much. After installing Boost module, i have troubles with uploading images. I can upload them, but only thumbnails are saved. Big image in sites/default/files/imagecache is not created. I tried to play with permissions, but didnt work. I have no idea where the problem is. What did boost module change that images cant be uploaded?
What shall I do?
This is critical. I tried to uninstall the module, but the problem still persists.

Comment: after disabling the boost module does the imagecache functionality come back, or even with boost disabled there are still problems. What errors are there when a page with an image that should be processed with imagecache is accessed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost is not the issue here. If the module is uninstalled and you still have a problem then it's not Boost. To be 100% sure make sure to get rid of the htaccess rules. I have not idea why people like to blame boost but it does happen.